# How to transfer a logic to JSON and execute it in Java?

Tags: java, json

I have an object with fields `a` and `b`. For example, I need to add `object.a+10` logic to JSON, and then pass this JSON to Java and perform an action on the object and its field `a`.

I want to write, for example, like this:

```
{
"object" : {
             "a": 1,
             "b": 10
           },
"operand1": "object.a",
"operand2": "10",
"operation": "+"
}
```

Or like this:

```
{
"object" : {
             "a": 1,
             "b": 10
           },
"action": "object.a + 10",
}
```

Is it possible? How can this be better implemented?

Comment: It might be helpful if you have some more context around why you're doing this. Is it in the context of an (HTTP) API or something?

Comment: I want to collect the formula on the frontend and transfer them to the backend for calculation

Comment: If it is simple arithmetic operation you don't have to calculate it in the backend. Just use client to calculate. If you still want to write the operation to the database or just log use the second format.

Comment: These can be quite complex calculations, I'm just showing an example.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you want to support both supplying directly a value as an operand and a reference to a value. The example with the reference is basically a [JSONPath](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc9535/) (well, almost).

> JSONPath defines a string syntax for selecting and extracting JSON
> (RFC 8259) values from within a given JSON value.

For simple use cases you could write your own simplified implementation, but for anything more complex you should use a library. I would suggest [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath), it is a java implementation of the JSONPath specification.

```
Map<String, Object> data = //parse json, use a library!!!

ToIntFunction<String> jsonPathOperandResolver = val -> JsonPath.parse(data).read("$." + val);
ToIntFunction<String> directValueOperandResolver = Integer::parseInt;

//analyze the value and pick the correct resolver
//for operand1 it's json path
int operand1 = jsonPathOperandResolver.applyAsInt(data.get("operand1").toString());
//for operand2 it's direct value
int operand2 = directValueOperandResolver.applyAsInt(data.get("operand2").toString());
//apply the operation on 1st and 2nd operand
```

The most important (missing part) in this example is that you write the logic to select the correct resolver based on the value. A simplified example, based on delegation may look like this:

```
class DelegatingOperandResolver implements ToIntFunction<String> {

  @Override
  public int applyAsInt(String value) {
    try {
      return directValueOperandResolver.applyAsInt(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
      return jsonPathOperandResolver.applyAsInt(value);
    }
  }
}
```

I would also strongly suggest to rethink your json structure and pick something, which does **not** constrain you into using `Map<String, Object>`. Basically something, which would allow you to parse into custom object, something like this:

```
public record CalculationData(String firstOperand, String secondOperand, String operation,
                              Map<String, Object> objToReferValueIn) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON library *Josson* can evaluate a statement inside a JSON.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"object\": {" +
    "        \"a\": 1," +
    "        \"b\": 10" +
    "    }," +
    "    \"action\": \"object.calc(a + 10)\"" +
    "}");

// Use eval()
Double answer = josson.getDouble("eval(action)");
System.out.println(answer.toString()); // Output: 11.0

// Query directly
answer = josson.getDouble("object.calc(a + b)");
System.out.println(answer.toString()); // Output: 11.0

// Use maths expression x+y and provide parameters
answer = josson.getDouble("calc(x+y, x:object.a, y:object.b)");
System.out.println(answer.toString()); // Output: 11.0
```

The calculation expression is supported by another powerful math library *mXparser*.

https://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/using-internal-help/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first option and turn operation into a enum so that it can handle some operation.

Don't forget to add appropriate exception handling etc.

```
public class Calculation {
    private Operand object;
    private String operand1;
    private String operand2;
    private OperationEnum operation;
    
    // . . .

    public int calculate(){
       int number1 = Integer.parseInt(operand1 );
       int number2 = Integer.parseInt(operand1 );
       return operation.apply(number1, number2);
    }

}

public enum OperationEnum{
    PLUS("+", (a, b) -> a + b),
    MINUS("-", (a, b) -> a - b),
    DIVIDE("/", (a, b) -> {
        if (b == 0) throw new ArithmeticException("Cannot divide by zero");
        return a / b;
    }),
    MULTIPLY("*", (a, b) -> a * b);

    private final String symbol;
    private final BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> operation;

    Operation(String symbol, BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> operation) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public int apply(int a, int b) {
        return operation.apply(a, b);
    }
    // . . .
}
```

Comment: At what point is the string "object.a" converted to an object field here?

Comment: if you are using spring or jersey common web frameworks for web development they all have json support. They will handle and validate json before controller. Check out for GetMapping, Postmapping for spring boot

Comment: Frameworks convert json to an object, but they will not substitute the digit 1 instead of the string "object.a" for further calculations. My question is whether it is possible to specify in json an object and its field where the value lies, and then in java to take it from there and use it for calculations.